# Inject with multiple block parameters

Tags: ruby

The Sunspot gem for Solr has a method that requires a block with 2 elements:

```
search.each_hit_with_result do |hit,result|
```

and I'm using it to build a new hash of results like so:

```
results = Hash.new

search.each_hit_with_result do |hit,result|
  results[result.category.title] = hit.score
end
```

This is cool and everything but I can't help thinking there is a more 'ruby' way of doing it and I've been looking at the awesome `inject` method. I think something like the following should be possible but I can't get it to syntactically work. Anyone got any ideas?

```
search.each_hit_with_result.inject({})
{|newhash,|hit,result||newhash[result.category.title]=hit.score}
```

Comment: Map search into an array of title and score 2 element arrays, and then use `Hash[foo]` on that array of arrays. I'll write this up as a proper answer later on today.

Comment: Nevermind, tokland beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object#enum_for](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Object.html#method-i-enum_for) is designed exactly for this:

```
hit_results = search.enum_for(:each_hit_with_result)
results = Hash[hit_results.map { |hit, res| [res.category.title, hit.score] }]
```

In my opinion, code should never expose `each_xyz` methods, they promotes smelly imperative code (as you rightly detected). That kind of methods were understandable when there were no [enumerators](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerator.html) and you needed to return data lazily, but now it should be considered an anti-pattern. They should return an enumerable or enumerator and let the user decide how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that method looks like what do you want:

```
search.each_hit_with_result.inject({}) { |new_hash, current| new_hash[current[0]] = current[1]; new_hash }
```

Hope its help you.

Comment: Yes. Quick test without SOLR: Hash.inject seems to behave the same as that each* method in that it passes 2 args. So: {1=>2, 3=>4}.inject({}) { |new_hash, current| new_hash[current[0]] = current[1]; new_hash }

Comment: You can use each_with_object instead of inject.